# Saving render result to use it again

Tags: forms, twig, symfony5

I'm trying to build a form in my controller, my form contain two "select" options which use the same database table field  "villes"
I want to to use this field twice, one time for city departure and another time for city arrival

```
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($vol)
                 ->add('hor_dep')
                 ->add('villes')
                 ->add('villes')
                 ->add('prix')
                 ->add('reduc', CheckboxType::class, array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Réduction'))
                 ->add('nbr_place')
                 ->getForm();
```

but when I try to render this form.html.twig

```
       <div class="col-lg-6">
     {{ form_label(form.hor_dep,'Heure de départ') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.hor_dep) }}
     {{ form_label(form.villes,'Ville de départ') }}
    {{ form_row(form.villes) }}
     {{ form_label(form.hor_arrivee,"Heure d'arrivée") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.hor_arrivee) }}
    {{ form_label(form.villes,"Ville d'arrivée") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.villes) }}
    
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
     {{ form_label(form.prix,'Prix') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.prix) }}
     {{ form_label(form.reduc,'possède une réduction ?') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.reduc) }}
     {{ form_label(form.nbr_place,'Nombre de place') }}
    {{ form_widget(form.nbr_place) }}
    </div>
```

it throws this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Field "villes" has already been rendered, save the result of previous render call to a variable and output that instead.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have to add two fields in your formType: `villeDepart` & `villeArrivee` (like what you did with the `heure`) because you don't want the first form field be overwritten by the second one.

In your mapping, the two fields will point to the same `villes` table, but each one will have a different value.